# Add link to `Add to Calendar` for ics file in erb email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, calendar, attachment, actionmailer

I've created a `confirmation email` using `ActionMailer` in Rails. My method for creating the email is as follows:

```
def session_confirmation_email_client(user, coach, date, session_ics, session_outlook, google_cal)
  @google_cal = google_cal
  @user = user
  @date = format_time(date.getlocal)
  @sender = "#{SENDER}"
  mail.attachments["session.ics"] = { mime_type: 'text/calendar', content: session_ics }
  mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Session Confirmation')
end
```

This properly adds the `session.ics` attachment to the email but now I want to include an `Add To Calendar` button which will download the attachment on click.

My erb template for the same looks as follows, at the moment:

```
<td align="right" valign="top">
  <%= link_to image_tag("https://s3.amazonaws.com/ical.svg"), LINK_TO_ATTACHMENT %>
</td>
```

I'm not sure what link to add over here? Is this way wrong? Basically I'm not sure how to add a download link for an email attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach an event in an email, you can't create a button inside the email that invokes the attached event.

When an event is attached to the email, most email clients do a great job detecting the attached event and provides an "Add to Calendar" link themselves.

In case you still want a backup "Add to Calendar" link in the email, then I would recommend that you use a solution like the "Direct URL Method" from AddEvent.com -  https://www.addevent.com/api/direct-url-method. (I'm behind AddEvent btw).

Most of our users who attach an event in emails use a mix. They attach an event using their Mail API and include "Add to Calendar" links in the email as well. Both can be accomplished using the "Direct URL Method".

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I actually went ahead and changed my method to follow your idea. I just push my `ics` file to S3 when it's created and people can download it now by clicking on the icon which points to S3. I'm marking your answer correct because my solution was similar to your answer; I just created it rather than using addEvent

Comment: My pleasure! It's all about methods - great approach solving it!

Comment: Hi. @anonn023432, I have the same issue you mentioned.
Did you find another solution to add 'Add to calendar' link, and the event will automatically will added to your calendar (google, outlook etc.) instead of download the file from S3?
Thanks!

Comment: @anonn023432, may I ask how you created it please ? I would like to use the same method.